# How to show Streetview on maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-street-view

How can we write code to show the Streetview like the below shown image in android?
If i'm applying

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

it's showing as normal view. But i need to show like the below image.

[image: streetview like below]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247044/google-streetview-existence-function-not-javascript/4747663#4747663

Comment: You can use WebView see [here is demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586441/how-to-display-a-mapview-and-a-streetview-simultaneously/13717085#13717085) or you can [send an Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447723/about-android-google-api-streetview/3773346#3773346).

Answer (score 0):

The streetview is Deprecated.
From the Documentation:
*@Deprecated
public void setStreetView(boolean on)
Deprecated. Street view availability highlighting is no longer supported. This method operates as a no-op.*
Check the documentation that was downloaded with the Google Aps.
Hope this helps
Cliff

Comment: as i seen some of the apps in the market they have implemented that so how come they did?

Comment: Hi Kumar  I am new at this too, so I can't help on that.  Usually deprecated means there is something better, but I have not found it.